# Export from Excel into XML using XML Literals + VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-literals

I need help with this....
    I have Excel file with data.
    And I need to export it into XMLfile, using XML Literals in VB.NET
    I need some XML-file a a result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://...">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://....xsd">           
            <Header>
                <Verb>cancel</Verb> 
            </Header>
            <Request>
                <ID>VALUE-1</ID>
                <ID>VALUE-2</ID>
                <ID>VALUE-3</ID>
                ......
            </Request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Where VALUE-1, VALUE-2,....and so on - I get them from Cells with Ron Numer    i and column Number = 2.
In VB.NET in Loop I did this like:

```
While Not this condition
    While Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value))
    'Check next condition with IF
                   If LCase(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 25).Value) = "y" Then
                   'Add XElement object into another one XML Element from main XDocument
                        objRequestCANCEL.Add(objIDCANCEL)
                        'Add Value for this new Element
                        objIDCANCEL.Value = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
                   End If
                   'Go to next Row and do the same - add XELement if condition is OK here
    iRow = iRow + 1
    End While
```

Here objIDCANCEL As XElement in main XDocument
        I used in this case XElements like Variables.But Now I need something like creation document without variables like this:

```
Dim XDoc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
                                  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://...">
                                        <soapenv:Header/>
                                        <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://....xsd">   
                                            <Header>
                                                <Verb>create</Verb>    
                                                <ID><%= varValue %> </ID>
                                                .....HERE I NEED ADD IN LOOP ALL VALUES FROM ALL ROWS IN EXCEL FILE.....
                                            </Header>
                                            <Request>
                                            </Request>
                                        </RequestMessage>
                                    </soapenv:Body>
                                </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Write me please, how can I re-write this Loop here ?

Comment: You can't put in any loop statement in there, you can only use a LINQ `From .. Select` expression.

Comment: But how looks like LINQ instead of Loop in my case with my conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example using LINQ and a worksheet to read out the first column (`1`) of the rows `1 .. 3` and populate some XML literals:

```
    Dim excel As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
    excel.Workbooks.Open("sheet1.xlsx")
    Dim sheet As Excel._Worksheet = excel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim cells As Excel.Range = sheet.Cells

    Dim doc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0"?>
                           <root>
                               <values>
                                   <%= From i In Enumerable.Range(1, 3) Select <value>
                                                                                   <%= cells(i, 1).Value %>
                                                                               </value> %>
                               </values>

                           </root>

    doc.Save(Console.Out)
```

Output then is e.g.

```
<root>
  <values>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
  </values>
</root>
```

Adapt that to your XML format and Excel sheet contents as needed.

Comment: I think that is what i need! Thanks a lot!